# Let $F$ be a field of order $2^n$. Prove that characteristic of $F$ is 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I figure that Lagrange's theorem and the fact that the characteristic of an integral domain is either $0$ or prime should be used, but just can't figure it out exactly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$F$ cannot have characteristic $0$, because it is a finite field.

If $F$ has characteristic $p>0$, then $1$ generates an additive subgroup of order $p$. By Lagrange's theorem, $p$ divides the order of the whole group $F$, which is $2^n$.

Since $p$ is prime, $p=2$.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain why $1$ generates an additive subgroup of order $p$(any theorem)?

Comment: The additive subgroup generated by $1$ is $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,p-1\}$ (since $p\cdot 1=0$). @MUH

Answer (score 5):

By Cauchy's Theorem, the additive group of $\;\Bbb F\;$ has an element of order two, meaning

$$a+a=a(1+1)=0\implies 1+1=0$$

and clearly (why?) this is the minimal possible integer with this characteristic...

Comment: :nice approach :)

Comment: haven't learnt Cauchy's theorem :(